# Wordpress wp-admin suddenly lost its style

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm really baffled about this. In the last couple of days (since I was using the site last), my Wordpress install has suddenly lost almost all of its formatting (only the top bar seems to work.

[image]

The CSS does seem to be loading, but its missing tons of them:

[image]

Here is the same page on another site (same version of WordPress);

[image]

I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this all of a sudden. The front end if fine, just to reiterate that.

**UPDATE:** thanks to someone over at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, I followed these instructions:

> Try the following: 1) Clear your browser cache. 2) Re-install
>   WordPress (keep wp-content and your database, just reinstall the core
>   files)

....and that has now fixed it :) Thanks to everyone who offered suggestions though!

Comment: Doesn't appear to a programming issue...you'll have better luck on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe it's http/https problem

Comment: @TennysonH - thanks, will post it there and see if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: @ghyjek - thanks for the suggestion. The whole site is on HTTP, so don't think thats the issue. The entire styles just seem to be missing - i.e its not loading dashboard.css, editor.css, and a few others... which is most likely why its screwed :/

Answer (score 15):

Another solution, try adding this to `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I fixed this quite a while ago by re-uploading WP, and then it worked. Still not quite sure why it did it, but I will be sure to remember this for the future, in case it helps :)

Comment: Remove that line from wp-config.php will solve the issue `wordpress 5.3`

Comment: define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false ); worked for me. Do I need to remove the line in the future? Do I need to wait for updates to get it working again without this line?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by re-registering dashicons.
I disabled it fully with:

```
wp_deregister_style( 'dashicons' );
```

After I commented out this line it worked normally. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and fixed it by opening the Wordpress table wp-options in phpmyadmin (or the like).
Make sure your two entries "siteurl" and "home" are the correct.
http://yourwordpressurl.something, if the domain stated in these two fields are wrong the css style is the first to go.

To check:

```
 select * from wp_options where option_name in ('siteurl', 'home');
```

Then you can update if it's not.